# How to get all interfaces (or any tokens) in neovim LSP?

Tags: lua, neovim, language-server-protocol

I'm trying to get all the interfaces from a given buffer. To do so, I want to get all the tokens and filter out everything except the interfaces. However, when I try to make a call to the LSP: I get nothing back.

```lua
local bufnr = vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()
local params = vim.lsp.util.make_text_document_params()
local result = vim.lsp.buf_request_sync(bufnr, "textDocument/documentSymbol", params, 2000)
print(vim.inspect(result))
```

All I'm getting is an empty map. I'm clearly missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what.

```lua
{
  [2] = {
    result = {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Language server you're using probably didn't implement the method you're looking for. You can try other LSPs and compare.
See the NOTE from the Neovim [docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html#lsp-api),

> lsp-method 
> Methods are the names of requests and notifications as
> defined by the LSP specification. These LSP requests/notifications are
> defined by default:
>
> ```
> callHierarchy/incomingCalls
> callHierarchy/outgoingCalls
> textDocument/codeAction
> textDocument/completion
> textDocument/declaration*
> textDocument/definition
> textDocument/documentHighlight
> textDocument/documentSymbol
> textDocument/formatting
> textDocument/hover
> textDocument/implementation*
> textDocument/publishDiagnostics
> textDocument/rangeFormatting
> textDocument/references
> textDocument/rename
> textDocument/signatureHelp
> textDocument/typeDefinition*
> window/logMessage
> window/showMessage
> window/showDocument
> window/showMessageRequest
> workspace/applyEdit
> workspace/symbol
> ```
>
> NOTE: These are sometimes not implemented by servers.

Also, make sure your LSP is configured correctly, just in case.